# Pylint errors in GitLab pipeline but not locally

Tags: gitlab, pylint

I've been struggling to find the root cause of pylint errors that occur only when pylint command run as part of lint job of the cicd GitLab pipeline. Locally I cannot reproduce it.

Pylint version in CI and locally is the same: `2.17.1`.

There are also only specific types of error that occur when ran in gitlab, namely, those are:

`R0401: cyclic-import error`;
`R0801: duplicate-code`

Command ran in cicd pipeline job: `pylint --rcfile=auxiliary/pylint.rc --output-format=pylint_gitlab.GitlabCodeClimateReporter:pylint_code_climate.json,text my_repo | tee ./pylint/pylint.log || pylint-exit $?`

Anybody had similar experience and found a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same version of pylint in the CI and locally?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, discrepancy in version has been ruled out. Both are 2.17.1.

Answer (score 0):

When pylint is run with multiple cores (e.g. `--jobs=0`), `cyclic-import` and `duplicate-code` messages might be incorrectly silenced. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/374) in pylint. Is it possible you're running with multiple cores locally? I suggest either disabling those messages or always running pylint with an identical number of jobs.